# Find the value $P_n(1)$ of the Legendre polynomials from their generating function

Tags: fourier-series, generating-functions, transformation, legendre-polynomials

Here is the question:

> Using $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)r^n=(1-2rx+r^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ find the value of $P_n(1)$

I am unsure how to handle this question. I did the following and would like clarification on if it is correct or how to correct it if not.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(1)r^n=(1-2r+r^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}=(r-1)^{-1}$

Not sure where to go from here?

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(1)r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}=\sum r^n$ for $|r|<1$ (i.e., Khanickus's answer right below).

Comment: @Nobody So surely this would mean $P_n(1)=0$? I am unsure about equating the coefficients?

Comment: Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_{n}(1)r^n$ converges to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n=1/(1-r)$ and power series are unique, equating the coefficients on the $r^n$ terms of both these series demonstrates that $P_{n}(1)=1$ for each $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1/(1-r)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ equating coefficients gives $P_n(1)=1$.

Comment: sorry equating what coefficients?